# How to open SPI on Pico i.MX7D

Tags: android-things

In my Android Things project using a RPi3 I connect MCP3008 ADC to the SPI CS/MISO/MOSI/SCLK pins BCM8/BCM9/BCM10/BCM11 respectively, open them `service.openGpio(<pin>)` and scan periodically to read analog input from connected pots. Full source: https://github.com/tomaszrykala/MidiMixerAndroidThings/blob/master/things/src/main/java/com/tomaszrykala/midimixerandroidthings/control/adc/MCP3008.java

I am trying to achieve the same result with a Pico i.MX7D board but whether I try to opent the CS port for example with `"SPI3 (SS0)"` or  `"SPI3.0"` or `GPIO6_IO26` I get every time `android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Unknown I/O name SPI3 (SS0) (code 19)` (replace the name with any of the preceding examples).

Is there a way to reuse my logic for the Pi by opening the SPI gpio on the Pico at all?

Comment: what version of AndroidThings are you running?

Comment: 0.6.1 . I flashed the Pico this morning.

Comment: have you tried `"SPI3.1"` https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/blob/master/apa102/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/driversamples/BoardDefaults.java#L36

Comment: If you look at the I/O graph or print `new PeripheralServiceManager().getSpiBusList()` you should be able to see the name of the port you want to use: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d-pico-io.html

Comment: So it looks like what the library is leveraging is the Pi's ability to open Alternative Fuctions, eg. SPI, as GPIO, which the Pico does not. Whether this works as a true SPI I am confused because on one hand the MCP is meant to be used with SPI signals, like MOSI, MISO etc. , yet these are open as GPIOs here, where SPI should apparently be open only as `openSpiDevice(...)`, not `openGpio(...)`. Perhaps I have misenderstood something about the use of the library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Things, a signal name is tied to a function. The RPi3 board uses dynamic pinmux support which allows Peripheral I/O to open the same pin for alternate functions at runtime. Each function, though, has a unique signal name (e.g. `BCM8` and `SPI0.SS0` are the same physical pin). This is why the [pinout diagram](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi-io.html) has a table with multiple signal names for certain pins.

The Pico boards do not have internal pinmux support at the moment, so there are no alternate signals available for each pin. Each pin has a dedicated function, which is why the [pinout diagram](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d-pico-io.html) only shows one signal name for each.

Comment: So does this mean that when we open the SPI0 pins in alternate functions we don't interact with the SPI bus at all?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You would never pass a signal name like `SPI0.1` to anything other than `SpiDevice`. If you were to open one of the same physical pins (e.g. `BCM8`) as a `Gpio`, that would not be going through the SPI subsystem on the chip.